# php can't find zend extension (ioncube)

Tags: php, configure

On one server I've got `php-5.6.7-1` and I installed `ioncube` there without a hitch. I put `ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so` into `/usr/lib/php5/20131226`, and added `zend_extension = ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so` to `php.ini`.

But that doesn't work for the other server. I've got `php-5.4.4-14+deb7u4` there. I put `ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so` into `/usr/lib/php5/20100525`, and added `zend_extension = ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so` to `php.ini`.

```
$ php -i | grep extension_dir
extension_dir => /usr/lib/php5/20100525 => /usr/lib/php5/20100525
$ php --version
Failed loading ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so:  ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u4 (cli) (built: Aug 23 2013 14:37:41) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

And now to the fun part:

```
$ strace php --version
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff2cc8cf60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7fff2cc8cf60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7fff2cc8cf60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff2cc8cf60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7fff2cc8cf60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7fff2cc8cf60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=20480, ...}) = 0
open("/lib/tls/x86_64/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff2cc8cf60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/tls", 0x7fff2cc8cf60)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64", 0x7fff2cc8cf60)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff2cc8cf60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls", 0x7fff2cc8cf60)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64", 0x7fff2cc8cf60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
munmap(0x7f1f3e188000, 37265)           = 0
write(2, "Failed loading ioncube_loader_li"..., 128Failed loading ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so:  ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
) = 128
open("/usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysqlnd.so", O_RDONLY) = 6
...
```

On the first server `php` apparently loads the library without any problem:

```
$ strace php --version
...
futex(0x7fbf391860c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
open("/usr/lib/php5/20131226/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220o\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
...
```

Has it something to do with some `configure` options, that are preventing it from searching for zend extensions inside `/usr/lib/php5/20100525`? Is there a way to find them out? What am I to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the full path:

```
zend_extension = /full/path/to/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so
```

I don't know from when is this change, but one was used to always specify full path for `zend_extension` until a build of PHP 5.5 (on Fedora, but I think it's the same on Debian).
I think it's a maintainer choice.

Comment: It seems as of [php-5.5.0](http://news.php.net/php.general/324872) one can specify path to zend extensions relative to `extension_dir` directory.

Comment: @x-yuri thank you for the information. I've read the changelogs but was unable to find such a feature. So thank you for your follow-up, I understand now.